# phpunit (install) error

Tags: phpunit

i have tried installing phpunit the install itself seems fine.

i can run "phpunit" but when i try to run a test "phpunit test.php" i get

```
'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PHPUnit 3.3.17 by Sebastian Bergmann.

..

Time: 0 seconds

OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
```

so as u can see, phpunit runs but with something wierd 1st. and in netbeans, i get "'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." and it stops

Answer (score 13):

When you installed PHPUnit, it made a `phpunit.bat` file in your PHP installation directory. For example, mine was at `C:\PHP\phpunit.bat`.

Open up that file in Notepad. At the bottom you'll see a line that looks something like

```
set PHPBIN=".\php.exe"
```

Edit that to a correct absolute path, such as

```
set PHPBIN="C:\php.exe"
```

If the path has a space in it, you need to escape it with double quotes, such as

```
set PHPBIN="""C:\some long path\php.exe"""
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and when run this command in:

**phpunit -v**

I saw following error :

> 'pupunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I copy the **phpunit.bat** in system32 folder( C:\Windows\System32 ) and it work.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a bug in PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/ticket/826). It was fixed in version 3.4.

Just upgrade to the newest version:

```
pear channel-update
pear install phpunit/PHPunit
```

and it should work correctly.

Comment: It appears that your link is invalid, though I found [another one that is very similar](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/823), the main difference being that this issue is specificaly when using process isolation (`@runInSeparateProcess`). It's supposed to be fixed in 3.7.15.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a DOS 8.3 notation error.
You should change the path-name in phpunit.bat to the shorthand notation.

You can find this notation by browsing in the DOS-prompt with the following command:
dir /o:e /p /x

(Or use the double quotes like Nicholas mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Here "C:\program.." is the issue. While running phpunit, it is not able to recognize it.
So You can refer the link [Installing PHPUnit On Windows](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2011/04/installing-phpunit-on-windows.html) for cross checking PHPUnit installation.
It should help you.